Half-bridge on-time positive current slope details
As shown in the LTspice simulation, I am trying to build a simple HB converter. When the HS is ON, the current increases with a positive slope ((Vin/2)/Lm). After that the Lm current continues with a decreasing slope, D2 is conducting, voltage drop of Lm -Vin/2.
The current will continue in the same direction as D2. This is understandable, but what is the ON time dependency of the diode? What is a parameter for di/dt in that time? If this current takes a long time, it is reflected to the secondary side. Is it possible to see it in a real scenario?
V(N007,N008)-v(Lp)
V(A,B)*12.6 -v(Ls)'
V(sec+)*12.6-v(sec+)'
V(n005)*12.6-v(C3)'
I(L1)/12.6-i(L1)'
-I(Ls)/12.6-i(Ls)'
Uptaded: schematic is changed (13.05.2024 07:05)



What do you mean "on time dependency"? Afraid I cannot parse this. Dependency of the "on" time, the forward-bias time, the flyback pulse duration? || The waveforms are incongruous with the circuit shown. Is there more to the schematic that you aren't showing?

I added the full of schematic @TimWilliams

What do you mean "on-time dependency"?  When HS is turned, why the I_Lp current contınue with a negative slope? Curent continue with D2, okey but di/dt depends on what? it is only short amount of time in dead time. @TimWilliams

I can't see V(hs) and V(ls) in the plot, but if you plot V(Lp minus side) (whatever that node is; not all nodes are labeled), the capacitor voltage, you will find your answer.

If you update/change your original question, please add a line indicating this change, and the date/time of the update.

@TimWilliams I added the V(hs) and V(ls) as you requested. Everything is labeled.

You also need to understand what the output diode bridge (D3 to D6) is doing after the HS (or LS) has turned OFF.  Plot v(sec+) and the currents of each diode D3 to D6.  This will be an important clue for your understanding.

No, this node: https://i.sstatic.net/ABRJRi8J.png It has no net label so I have no name to call it.

@TimWilliams >> N008

What are the specifications for this DC-DC converter?  Power, Vin range, Vout range, Iout range, efficiency.  Any constraints, eg: maximum Fs, type of devices, magnetic components?

@FabioBarone I just tried to understand the topology detail, especially DCM.

You need to be consistent with reflecting variables to the primary side.  Otherwise you won't understand what affects the primary currents to answer your question.  So refect all diode currents to primary side.  Plot the current of all four diodes, what it reveals will be valuable.

@FabioBarone I added the sec. diode current with reflection.

Re: The new plot with currents of D3 to D6, too many traces, some are not visible, eg: pink i(L1). May need to put these on 2 or 3 charts. Make sure all variables are visible, otherwise confusing.

@FabioBarone D3 and D4 currents are perfectly overwritten by D6 and D5 respectively; the plot order appears to be the drawing order.  I(L1) is hidden by the upper envelope of  D5 and D6.

What is V(C3) DC? The axis label is cut off in the second set of plots. It looks like twenty-something. This is very different from the 11.5 or 12V shown on the schematic.

@TimWilliams  Hi Tim, yes, I understand - it's one of the hints that I'm hoping the OP will pick up on.  But having a clear visible trace for i(L1) is key to understanding the primary side waveforms.

What happened to the ringing?

@TimWilliams  All parasitic C's were removed.  :-)

Suggestion:
Plot the following variables in the correct time relation on the same plot, and with the same vertical scale for current and voltage.  Variables marked with a prime "'", are on the secondary side of the transformer, and should be multiplied/divided (voltage, current) by the transformer ratio to reflect to the primary side (this is easy to do in LTspice, which I assume is the simulator you are using).



#
sim id
description




1
i(L2)
current in the input filter choke.


2
i(Lp)
current in the transformer (Tx) primary winding.


3
v(Lp)
voltage across Tx primary winding.


4
i(Ls)'
current in Tx secondary winding.


5
v(Ls)'
voltage across Tx secondary winding.


6
i(Lp)'
current in the output filter inductor.


7
v(C3)'
voltage across output filter capacitor.


8
i(R4)'
current in the output load.


9
v(sec+)
voltage at positive terminal of output diode bridge



Update: added item 9 to table.
Once you have done this, you should easily see what is happening and be able to answer your own questions.  I can make some comments about the answers, but it will not be obvious until you see those plots.

This is understandable, but what is the ON time dependency of the diode?

D2 current flows due to energy stored in the transformer (Tx) primary in two inductors: leakage inductance and magnetising inductance.  The leakage inductance is not shown on your schematic as a separate discrete component but it has been set by the K factor you used, if K=1 then leakage is zero.  It is probably a good idea to set K=1 to start with, then gradually make this non-zero to understand what effect leakage inductance has on your circuit.
The starting amplitude of the current in D2 is set by the current in the primary-side magnetising inductance of Tx (Lp).  This current is much lower than the peak of i(Lp) at the turn-off of the primary switches since the Tx secondary is now no longer carrying the load current (L1); you will find that the output load current i(L1) flows through two (or more) diodes of the output rectifier (D3 - D6), and not through Ls.
"ON time dependency of the diode": You will find that D2 ON time is not strongly dependent upon load current (ie: current in Lp at the instant of primary switch turn-off).  It will be far more strongly dependent upon supply voltage, V3.
When the current in D2 reaches zero, Tx primary voltage is no longer clamped to the supply rails, and it will oscillate, as you can see in the plot.

What is a parameter for di/dt in that time?

di/dt for i(D2) will be determined by primary voltage (set by V3) being applied across two series inductors: Lp, and leakage L.  Of these two, Lp is by far the larger, so it will dominate di/dt.

Is it possible to see it in a real scenario?

Well, LTspice will accurately simulate a real-world circuit.  I have used it for over 15 years, and it has always been right - when it has not been right it was because I did not set up the simulation to match the real circuit.

Update: moved comment into answer, as follows:
I also suggest you remove all parasitic components so that you get a better understanding of the basic function of your circuit, without the extra complexity introduced by such things as parastic MOSFET and diode capacitance, and transformer parasitic winding capacitance.
To do this, simply set parameters Coss & Coss1 to 0 (or divide their present value by 1000), and set R5 to R7 to present value x 1MEG.
This will greatly clean up the waveforms by reducing much of the ringing you are seeing.

I did not totally understand your suggestions. I added one more plot maybe you can check.

Suggest changing K to 1 first, this removes "leakage inductance", which is just adding unwanted complexity at this stage.  Also I suggest changing all the Rs in the parasitic Tx capacitors to high values, say multiply these by 1MEG.  Do you know how to multiply a trace in LTspice?

Turns ratio of your transformer: Lp=510uH Ls=3.54uH.  I suggest you read this:  https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-basic-steps-for-simulating-transformers.html

I added without leakage inductance as shown in last photo. @Fabio Barone

Re: turns ratio.  Did you read the link?

n=12.6, last photo updated correctly @Fabio Barone

I am responding to your comment: Photos are updated (added 11.05.2024,08:38 CET).     You also need to understand what the output diode bridge (D3 to D6) is doing after the HS (or LS) has turned OFF. Plot v(sec+) and the currents of each diode D3 to D6. This will be an important clue for your understanding.

I have added v(sec+) to the table in my answer.  I also suggest you remove all parasitic components so that you get a better understanding of the basic function of your circuit, without the extra complexity introduced by such things as parastic MOSFET and diode capacitance, and transformer parasitic winding capacitance.  To do this, simply set parameters Coss & Coss1 to 0 (or divide their current value by 1000), and set R5 to R7 to current value x 1MEG.

The voltage across the inductor determines the rate of current change. When the diode conducts, it is the diode and capacitor series voltage that determine the current, since those are the only components connected to the inductor at the time, sans parasitics.

hasn’t forgotten Monica This is already I know, I need to have more deeper explanation for exactly what I am asking.

@analog_designer: Then we need "deeper" information in the question.  In particular HS and LS (time aligned with other signals),  MYSW,  C1, C7, Coss..

@RussellH I added other sıgnals?
